# Execute macros or scripts based on Magic Trackpad 2 Force Touch

Tags: applescript, automator, script, magic-trackpad

I’m looking at getting a Magic Trackpad 2 with Force Touch, but want to know if I can create macros for the Force Touch actions?

I’m not taking about the the built in basic Apple support, but full on macros and scripting. I can’t find this listed on the Apple site other than “as developers add support”.

Has anyone done this with say BetterTouchTool, AppleScript or even Automator yet?

Thanks!

Comment: [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/bettertouchtool-with-force-touch-trackpads/) has supported Force Touch for quite a while.

Comment: @tubedogg you are correct that BetterTouchTool can fire actions based on Force Touch interaction now (it couldn't when I asked my question), but it can't fire a macro script directly without it calling another application. It works, but it's kind of unwieldily.